# PHP—Empty String Help

Tags: php

The CMS I'm using has a plugin that pulls a series of pages based on how you've tagged those pages. Everything is working fine, but I need to display the number of pages returned after a user sends a query.

The variable that the number of records is stored in is a string. The small script I'm writing tries to check if this string is blank, and if so echo nothing, but if it's not blank echo the number of pages returned.

```
<?php

if ($count !== ''){
    echo "text";
}

?>
```

However, whenever it's passed when the string is supposed to be empty it treats it as if it is not. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what the string contains that it's not empty.

I found a resource about converting strings to integers but it set it to 0. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but if you want to echo nothing when $count is blank, and echo the number that's in it when it's not, what's the problem with just doing this: `echo $count`?

Comment: Try using `if(!empty($count))`

Comment: Try writing $count = ''; before your code

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure $count is a string? If you're sure, then this: `if ($count) echo 'text';` should be equivalent to the code in your current version of your question.

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific, when $count isn't blank I need to echo $count along with some HTML. I did a var_dump on $count and it returned string(9) ""

Comment: string(9) "" means there's 9 spaces in there. a truly empty string would be string(0).

Comment: You have to check the source of your page. var_dump() doesn't wrap itself in a <pre> tag, for example $count = "\n\n\n\n"; var_dump($count); will display string(4) " " which doesn't seems logical, but viewing the source page will reveal the special chars.

Comment: What does `echo ord($count)` show? (That will tell you the ASCII value of the first character of this odd string you've got, and maybe give us a clue as to what the heck is in there...)

Answer (score 3):

$count will never be equal to ' ' if you trim it before.

Comment: I corrected my code above, tried it again, but it's still echoing "Text" even when it should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be equal to ' ' after trim, you should check if it is equal to an empty string and not a string with a white space. (trim deletes white spaces)

trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

`trim` removes all spaces, so `$count == ' '` will always be false if you trimmed first. The easiest change to your code would be to replace the `' '` with `''`. Or you could just do this: `echo trim($count) === '' ? '' : "text";`

Answer (score 0):

[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is going to remove all white-space characters from the beginning and end of the string. Unless there is content in the middle, you'll likely end up with a completely empty string. If you're testing for this, try checking [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [`is_null()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

```
if (empty($string)) {
  echo "String is empty.";
}
```

I find it's better using built-in functions instead of hard-coding a `==''` comparison.

Comment: I've tried empty() a couple times, and despite a var_dump showing that it's empty, it always returns as if there's something there. I'm not really sure what's going on....

Comment: @Vecta: Then I recommend forcefully dumping the string. Use something like: `for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($count); $a++) echo sprintf("%c (%d)",$count{$a}, ord($count{$a}));`

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump() to check the type and the content of the variable.
[Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: After a var_dump it returns: string(9) ""

Comment: And why don't you use empty()  or !empty()?

Comment: I've tried empty() but it acts as if it is not empty. if (!empty($count)) { echo "text";)} will always end up echoing

Comment: When the var_dump() prints the result and you check the source of the page, what do you see? Only string(9) ""? Did you try to write the string to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong; you've got "!==", where I'd swear you need to have "!=" (only one equals sign).  I'm not sure what "!==" would evaluate to, but I'd bet it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the comments that your "blank" string is not blank, but instead has something odd in it. Assuming that it's not too odd I'd just try this:

```
$count = intval($count);
if ($count) {
  echo 'text';
}
```

Though this assumes that the $count actually looks like a number to intval when it's got a number in it -- we may need to take a look at this "string" you're getting back in more detail to figure out what's really in it.

Hopefully you've already taken the advice given by others and looked at the resulting page source after doing a var_dump() -- otherwise I'd guess that $count has XML in it, or something else that won't render well if you dump it to an HTML page and view the page rather than the source...

If nothing else, you could really try brute-forcing it:

```
$count = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $count));
if ($count) {
  echo 'text';
}
```

...but really it'd be better to work out what this odd plug-in is giving you, and why. Which CMS and plugin is it? Are there some docs available for this thing that's returning $count to you? Do you have the plugin source?